# RichFaces 4.5 - Weblogic 11g - ReferenceError

Tags: jquery, oracle, weblogic, richfaces, weblogic11g

I'm working on an application using Struts and JSF 2 with RichFaces 4.5.4.

Everything works fine when the application runs on a Tomcat(7) server. But when I run it on a WebLogic(11gR1-10.3.6) server the JS resources are not loaded.

The rich:popupPanel gets the error: **ReferenceError: RichFaces is not defined**
And when I try to run a jQuery script I get: **ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**

I'm using `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` and I have this parameters in my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Those context parameters are for RichFaces 3.x, they don't do anything here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Makhiel.
Those are things that I already tried, with the sole purpose of not suggest the same thing.

Comment: Did you add the rich faces jars on the lib folder of your project?

Comment: Yes @Erick. The project works fine on a tomcat server.

Comment: But in the production environment we use WebLogic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that ResourceServlet wasn't automatically registered.

As explains [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Advanced_features.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Advanced_features-Resource_loading) ResourceServlet is automatically registered in the Servlet 3.0 and higher environments.

In the Servlet 2.5 and lower environments, it is necessary to register the ResourceServlet manually in the WEB-INF/web.xml configuration file:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.richfaces.webapp.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/org.richfaces.resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```